# Is there a way to use a property in JSON in another value of a property?

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

Not sure if the question makes sense so better to provide a code example.

```
    {
        "data": {
            "whatever": [{
                "id": "abcd12312",
                "title": null,
                "value": null,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "My text {{value}} one",
                        "value": "email@address.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "My text [value] one",
                        "value": "email@address.com"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    }
```

So I was thinking can you do anything with Mustache or is there another way without having to write JavaScript to insert the value inside the text?

What I am trying to do is to allow the user to change the text to what ever they want but have a pointer to the value which will be dynamic based on what email address the entered on a previous page.

Comment: so... you want to persist a particular value from another page? is that what you mean?  if the value was a function, you could have it make a call to a value stored in localStorage.

Comment: Best way would be to keep different placeholders like  preText, postText & val and you can Concatenate it where ever needed.

Comment: Using a value as a function is what i was looking at but this is not allowed in json. And the grunt build fails when i try to use this because the framework has been setup not to allow it.